# Ошибка с циклом while

Tags: c++, while

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int var1,var2, i=0;

    cout<<"1-y, 2-x: ";
    cin >> var1;

    cout<<"z: ";
    cin >> var2;
    var2++

    while(i < var2){
        if(var1 == 1){
            cout <<"*";
        }
        if(var1 == 2){
            cout<<"*"<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<":L"<<endl;
            i = var2;
        }
        i++
    }

}
```

Ошибки [Error] expected ';' before 'while', [Error] expected '}' at end of input.

Comment: серьезно? ну вот что не понятного в строчке: "expected ';' before 'while'"? Вам же компилятор сам говорит в чем проблема!

Comment: Ну должен же быть какой-то минимальный уровень вопросов, честное слово! Сколько секунд (не верю, что минут...) вы разбирались со своим кодом. прежде чем писать сюда? Точка с запятой пропущена... И не одна. И, кстати, если бы вы форматировали текст - заметили бы это сразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пропустили точку с запятой (;) после оператора инкремента в двух местах. После var2++ и i++